# Internet Explorer not loading some .js files

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

So, I've got this aspx page which includes 4 javascipt files like so:

```
<script src="Scripts/invoicePrimary.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/invoiceBillOfLading.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/invoiceCharge.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/invoiceInvoice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Each of those defines a variable. invoicePrimary declares `classPrimary`, invoiceBillOfLading defines `classBillOfLading`, etc.

Later on in the page, we make reference to `classPrimary`, which makes reference to the others. The problem is that only half of them are defined. Specifically, `classPrimary` and `classCharge` are defined, while `classBillOfLading` an `classInvoice` are undefined.

This only happens in IE. Both in IE9 and IE9 acting as IE8. The whole site is designed for IE, so the rest of the stuff doesn't work in other browsers, but this part does. Does anyone have any ideas? Edit: As a note, all files are loaded as seen in Visual Studio's Script Documents folder.

Edit: The actual code which has problems:

```
populateScreenFromObject: function() {
        if (invoiceFolder == null) return;
        if (invoiceFolder.BillOfLadings != null) classBillOfLading.AddList(invoiceFolder.BillOfLadings);
        if (invoiceFolder.Invoices != null) classInvoice.AddList(invoiceFolder.Invoices);
        if (invoiceFolder.Charges != null) classCharge.FirstTimeLoad(invoiceFolder.Charges);
        classInvoice.FirstTimeLoad();
        classCharge.DisableNonDraftRadios();
        classBillOfLading.Add(); // In case BOL number is prepopulated
    },
```

This is a function in `classPrimary`, which is called from the main page like so: `classPrimary.PopulateScreen();` At this point, `classCharge` is the only one of those classes which is defined. The only thing that happens before this is loading `invoiceFolder` data from json stored in a hidden field.

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that anybody will be able to help if you don't show the actual code involved.

Comment: Get Fiddler2 and see the requests (and responses). Do all the files return a sane MIME type (e.g. `text/javascript`)? Are some of the files served with compression/chunking? Also, see IE's debugging console (under F12): do you get any errors and/or warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was that the invoiced*.js files that weren't loading had a , at the end of the last function, so it wasn't expecting to end. IE8 just ignored this, as did other browsers, but IE9 threw a fit.

Answer (score -1):

Try it in the real IE8. IE9 has caused a lot of breakage in IE.

Comment: IE9 is the closest thing to a standards-compliant browser Microsoft has ever made. It didn't break IE, it *fixed* IE (mostly) - any version prior to 9 was already horribly broken.

Comment: That did it.  Gotta love IE. And our broken website designed to work with IE8.